# Epsilon Delta Proof?

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

I always have trouble with understanding the intuition/process of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs.  Could anyone assist me with understanding the solution to the following:

Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}&\text{ for }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0&\text{ for }(x,y)  = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$.  We need to find $\delta>0$ satisfying what?

Answer (score 2):

The proposition under consideration is: For every $\epsilon > 0,$ a $\delta > 0$ exists such that if $|x|, |y| < \delta$ then $|x^{4}/(x^{2} + y^{2})| < \epsilon.$

Let $\epsilon > 0.$ If $|x| = |y|$, then 
$$|\frac{x^{4}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}| = \frac{x^{2}}{2} < \frac{\delta^{2}}{2},$$
so, for $|x^{4}/(x^{2}+y^{2})|$ to be $< \epsilon$ it suffices to take
$$\delta := \sqrt{2\epsilon}.$$
Without loss of generality, let $|x| < |y|$ (because the case where $|x| > |y|$ leads to the same result.). Then again we have
$$|\frac{x^{4}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}| < \frac{x^{4}}{2x^{2}} = \frac{x^{2}}{2} < \frac{\delta^{2}}{2},$$
so taking
$$\delta := \sqrt{2\epsilon}$$
suffices.
Here we have completed the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\left|x^2\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq |x|^2\leq x^2+y^2=||(x,y)||^2$$

So, suppose we are given $\epsilon>0$. We need to give $\delta$ such that if $||(x,y)||<\delta$ then $\left|\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|<\epsilon$.

What about $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$?